# Problems mocking static class property

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I have a class that should log some things. The logger is defined like this.

```
export class Logger {
  public static client = ClientStrategy.create();

  public async logSth(msg: string) {
    params = {"testThing": msg};
    await Logger.client.updateItem(params);
}
```

```
export class ClientStrategy {
  public static create() {
    return new DatabaseClient(); // not important here just a factory, with a method updateItem
  }
}
```

I am trying to mock this in a jest test. I am trying to do mock this client strategy and a create method for this. But it is not working as I would have expected.

```
jest.mock("./ClientStrategy");
const mockClientStrategy = jest.mocked(ClientStrategy, false);

describe("Logger", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(<any>mockDatabaseClientStrategy, "create").mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        updateItem: () => {
          return {}
        } 
      };
    });
  });

   
  it("should log sth", async () => {
    const response = await Logger.logSth("testMsg");
    expect(response).not.tobeUndefined();
  });
});
```

but I get Cannot read property "logSth" of undefined. Can you help me what am I doing wrong here? I think that my mock should work fine, but unfortunately I got undefined for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `jest.mock()` and `jest.spyOn()` will work. But there is no need to use them together for your case. So let's just use the `jest.spyOn()` to solve your problem.

Since the `ClientStrategy.create` will execute when you import the `Logger` class, you need to add spy on `ClientStrategy.create` before importing the `Logger` class.

Besides, the `logSth` method is an instance method, NOT a class method.

E.g.

`Logger.ts`:

```
import { ClientStrategy } from './ClientStrategy';

console.log('ClientStrategy.create: ', ClientStrategy.create);
export class Logger {
  public static client = ClientStrategy.create();

  public async logSth(msg: string) {
    const params = { testThing: msg };
    return Logger.client.updateItem(params);
  }
}
```

`Logger.test.ts`:

```
import { ClientStrategy } from './ClientStrategy';
// import { Logger } from './Logger';

describe('Logger', () => {
  let mockClient;
  let Logger: typeof import('./Logger').Logger;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockClient = {
      updateItem: jest.fn(),
    };
    jest.spyOn(ClientStrategy, 'create').mockReturnValue(mockClient);
    Logger = await import('./Logger').then((m) => m.Logger);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('should log sth', async () => {
    mockClient.updateItem.mockResolvedValueOnce('fake value');
    const logger = new Logger();
    const response = await logger.logSth('testMsg');
    expect(response).toEqual('fake value');
  });
});
```

`ClientStrategy.ts`:

```
export class ClientStrategy {
  public static create() {
    return { updateItem: async (params) => 'real value' };
  }
}
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71938329/Logger.test.ts
  Logger
    ✓ should log sth (22 ms)

  console.log
    ClientStrategy.create:  [Function: mockConstructor] {
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
      getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/71938329/Logger.ts:3:9)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.57 s, estimated 11 s
```

You can uncomment the `import { Logger } from './Logger';` statement and comment the `import()` to check the log. You will see unmocked `ClientStrategy.create` method:

```sh
console.log
    ClientStrategy.create:  [Function: create]
```